# Defining default state for WebDriver to continue work with in further cases

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am trying to define a default webdriver state. 
This state of the webdriver is after a log-in and create script, which take care of accessing the website and creating a new workspace where i wish to continue testing from. I am trying to build the rest of the classes from this starting point.
Returning this driver and executing the next command works, but after i executed the first action in the workspace, i cant return to the desired default state so i can call on other individual classes with different functions on the site.

login script : new firefox driver, geturl, fill in info,click on confirm, return driver

create workspace: login script, continued with nagivagtion between menus and filling in workspace info, and creating it, and returning it.

code is long, wont paste it here.
My problem is that after creating a workspace and starting further actions, every time a new action is called, selenium goes through with all the login stuff and creation again.
I am not a very experienced coder, so i am asking for help. 
Is there i way i could define a public variable that can hold this state of the driver ? 
How can i revert to this state after executing actions?

i am currently assigning WebDriver driver = logInAndCreate() at the first line of each action, which obviously deals with that 2, and i end it in return driver;
msot of the actions i defined already on the site are few lines of code handling navigation, finding and acting on webelements and such. there are tons of options and writing self standing test case for all is not going to happen, so i decided to arrange actions into classes and build my cases from these parts.

Comment: I see that you have some doubts, but they should be more specific to be answered. This question could be considered "too broad" or "primarily opinion-based". Please, read this links to get more familiar with SO: [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The flow in your code is defined by you. You don't have to call the login every time, if not necessary. I would suggest you to check the Page Object pattern. Here you find two links to it: [Test Design Considerations](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp) and [Page Object - Martin Flower article](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html). I think this is a good start to clarify some doubts you may be facing.

Comment: Great references @Tom Thanks

Comment: Thank you. they helped me figure out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is no state with `WebDriver`, it's just a connection to a browser that you can use to send commands to the browser. Because of this, you can't revert the state of the site using `WebDriver`. Also, having a function return `driver` accomplishes nothing either because you aren't changing the state of the driver inside the function.

Probably your best bet is to get with your devs and see if there's a way you can create a cookie, etc. that contains state. For example, maybe once you log in with a user, a site cookie is created to indicate that a user is logged in. Rather than using the UI to log in, you could create the properly formatted cookie that puts the site in the state of a logged in user. That's just an example but that should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Sorted out, happened to be more of my lack of knowledge than cookies.
i simply didnt know i can use Webdriver driver in the brackets after the name of my class. im a beginner and its obvious :D